# How to display model error messages within notice in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a date validation in model which should display a message on page, but for some reason it isn't. I need this message to be shown in notice on error. Currently I just see the message in controller (Order not registered) but I need to see the reason (Delivery date should be from now). How can I do that?

**model**

```
  def delivery_date_from_now_only 
    if self.delivery_date.present? && self.delivery_date <=  Date.today
      self.errors.add(:delivery_date, messsage: 'Delivery date should be from now')
    end
  end
```

**controller**

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user = current_user
    if @order.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Order registered successfully'
      return redirect_to @order
    end
    @warehouses = Warehouse.all.order(:name)
    @suppliers = Supplier.all.order(:brand_name)
    @users = User.all.order(:name)
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Order not registered'
    render :new, status: 422
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you call `@order.valid?` it will validate your model an also populate `errors` for that object. that means `@order.errors.messages` will be a hash with `{ :delivery_date => ["Delivery date should be from now"]}` etc (other errors will be in there as well) which u can use to do some flashes.

Comment: but where do I call that? in def delivery_date_from_now_only?

Comment: @KelsonBatista in your `create` method like `if @order.valid? && @order.save`. but actually you would just check `if @order.valid?` and do the `save` in the if clause becaus save could also fail and you would need to handle that separately.